# Should *all* function templates be passed as rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference, std-function

I can't help but notice that all people writing templates for functions use rvalue references. I'm not sure I'm right, but it's a tendency I noticed. Here's my simple example:

```
template <typename SyncFunc>
void waitForEstablished(int check_period_in_ms, SyncFunc&& syncFunc)
{
    auto established_future = promise_established.get_future();
    while (established_future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(check_period_in_ms)) != std::future_status::ready)
    {
        syncFunc();
    }
    established_future.get();
}
```

**Explanation of this function:** In this function, I provide a waiting method for the user, and provide a mechanism for synchronization/refreshing of a GUI. It helps in separating concerns. The user provides the function that should be called every `check_period_in_ms` milliseconds to prevent things from blocking. This is useful for the case when in a GUI application, the following is how I call this:

```
commThreadController.waitForEstablished(10,[this](){QApplication::processEvents();});
```

The function `QApplication::processEvents()` processes the GUI event loop.

But I'm really puzzled on what kind of reference I should use (always rvalue? when should it be something else?) and whether it makes a difference in any extreme case.

Should I be passing all function templates by rvalue reference?

Comment: `&&` on a template parameter is not an rvalue reference but a forwarding  reference. See Forwarding references (and also reference collapsing) here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh, thanks! I didn't know that! So this is really not rvalue.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313  1st answer looks very comprehensive

Comment: I'm wondering whether I should delete the question...